# pytorch unpickling issue when using public repo code with my own files

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle

I'm trying to  execute the following code to evaluate a model's performance.

```
split = 'CS'
pkl_path = './data.pkl'

if split == 'CS':
    gt_file = './data/smarthome_CS_51.json'
    classes = 51

pkl = open(pkl_path, 'rb')
logits = pickle.load(pkl, encoding='latin1')
```

This code is taken from this git page so it's a public repo : https://github.com/dairui01/TSU_evaluation/blob/main/Frame_map/Frame_based_map.py

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-with-eval.py", line 484, in <module>
    logits = pickle.load(pkl, encoding='latin1')
_pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

WHen I use the example version provided in the repo, it works fine. But not sure why this error appears, because I am generating the .pkl file the same way as the parent repo documents it.

The .pkl file I am using and the json file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Y-EOwSNUT1r5dxTi1MP0668weZlnLfJ9?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you show how you're originally saving that pickle file?

Comment: @AKX The pickle file is generated when we do the training for the model, using this script https://github.com/dairui01/Toyota_Smarthome/blob/main/pipline/train.py, but I have uploaded the version I am using too (it's the same more or less just with diff directories etc)

Comment: There is no `pickle.dump` invocation in that file. (`pickle` is actually just imported, never used.) Are you sure these programs and their versions are meant to be compatible?

Comment: @AKX the code was designed to be for TSU (the model name) evaluation so I would assume that the code owners designed it to be compatible :) just not sure how to get it to work :)

Comment: Well... the original code uses `torch.save()`. Could you try if `torch.load()` instead of `pickle.load()` in your code does the trick?